# How to add High score to game

Tags: c#, xml

So I need to add a High score table to snake game, And when I google it I could not understand a thing. So could you guys explain to me by rule of thumb how to do it?

Here's code, I couldnt enter it here maybe it's too long.
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TxPcQzp2)

Comment: You should add a minimal example, including what you already tried and how it failed. Not just the your whole code and a vague problem description.

Comment: I do agree with Schore, there are 100's of ways to do this so knowing the direction you are trying to go would be helpful. Database/TextFile ......

Comment: Try searching for questions that deal with "How to persist data between executions" or something like that..  You'll find plenty of resources.  In this case, you'll likely want to find a method involving serialization to a file.

Answer (score 1):

On the end of game (when player score is visible) create some method to save score in structured file, like XML (use System.IO). XML file can be loaded straight to DataSet, and DataTable created in DataSet is great source for keeping hight scores. You can sort it asc/desc "on the fly".

EDIT:
According to @workabyte wish I will provide some code samples (but not full code - just tips to show "how to").

1) XML structure for keeping scores can be very simple:

```
<scores>
   <score>
      <playerName>Some Name</playerName>
      <points>100</points>
   </score>
</scores>
```

2) reading XML file to DataSet object:

```
DataSet scoresDataSet = new DataSet();
string xmlPath = @"c:\MyGameFolder\MyXML.xml";
scoresDataSet.ReadXML(xmlPath);
```

So your DataSet structure will be created and fulfilled with data from XML file. It should contains one DataTable object called "score" with columns "playerName" and "points".

3) get DataTable from DataSet:

```
DataTable scoresDataTable = scoresDataSet.Tables["score"];
```

4) binding DataTable to DataGridView control (I believe you have placed this control on proper form):

```
yourGridViewName.DataSource = scoresDataTable;
```

5) change column headers of DataGridView:

```
yourGridViewName.Columns["playerName"].HeaderText = "Player";
yourGridViewName.Columns["points"].HeaderText = "Score";
```

6) adding new score (sample code for some button for example):

```
scoresDataTable.Rows.Add();
scoresDataTable.Rows[scoresDataTable.Rows.Count - 1]["playerName"] = "Player2";
scoresDataTable.Rows[scoresDataTable.Rows.Count - 1]["score"] = "200";
```

As you can see your DataGridView refreshes automatically. You must remember, that steps in 5) was just for nice GridView view and you still have DataSource with different column names than HeaderText property.

7) saving DataSet into XML:

```
scoresDataSet.WriteXML(@"c:\MyGameFolder\MyXML.xml");
```

8) sorting DataGridView descending (higher score on the top):

```
yourGridViewName.Sort(yourGridViewName.Columns["points"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

That's all. Thank you for reading and I hope it helps.

Comment: good answer but would be a lot better if you could add some actual examples as to how he would do this

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple why not just use a text (csv/json) file.

Like said in other answer, you would need to capture the information at the end, if you are not interested in names only the score it would be simpler but either way you can approach the same way.

If you are going to keep a list of lets say top 10 then you would want to 
-- read the file
-- add the new score
-- order by score
-- write the top 10

[File.ReadAllLines(filepath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will can be used to consume the file. then you would want to parse the data into numbers.

if you save the file like

`name,score`

you can do something like

`var scores = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(line => new HighScore{ name=line.Split(',').First(), score=line.Split(',').Last()).ToList()`

`scores.Add(new HightScore(value,value))`

Then you can use [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`File.WriteAllLine(scores.Take(10));`